# xpath:to eliminate text in tag a href

Tags: html, xpath

I have the html as below and want to eliminate the text inside tag a href

```
<td>BetaShares Managed Risk Global Share Fund</td>
<td class="text-center"><a href="/asx/wrld" target="_blank">WRLD</a></td>
<td class="text-center">0.39%</td>
<td class="text-center">N/A</td>
<td>A broadly diversified portfolio of global shares - <a href="http://www.betashares.com.au/products/name/managed-risk-global-share-fund" target="_blank">Link</a></td>
</tr><tr><td><img alt="iShares Logo" src="/sites/default/files/etfs/logos/ishares-logo-icon.png" /></td>
<td>iShares Core MSCI World All Cap</td>
<td class="text-center"><a href="/asx/iwld" target="_blank">IWLD</a></td>
<td class="text-center">0.16%</td>
<td class="text-center">MSCI World Investible Market</td>
<td>Covers large, mid and small-capitalisation stocks across developed markets which comply with MSCI's size, liquidity, and free-float criteria - <a href="https://www.blackrock.com/au/intermediaries/products/283117/" target="_blank">Link</a></td>
</tr><tr><td><img alt="iShares Logo" src="/sites/default/files/etfs/logos/ishares-logo-icon.png" /></td>
```

My desired output is

```
BetaShares Managed Risk Global Share Fund,WRLD,iShares Core MSCI World All Cap,IWLD
```

I try with

```
output = tree.xpath('//td[not(@class)][not(contains(.,"href"))]/text()')
```

but it returns undesirable answer.

```
BetaShares Managed Risk Global Share Fund,A broadly diversified portfolio of global shares -,iShares Core MSCI World All Cap,MSCI World Investible Market
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required text nodes only:

```
//tr/td[not(@class) and not(a)]/text() | //tr/td/a[not(../preceding-sibling::td[@class])]/text()
```

This should return you text node only from `td` without `class` attribute and link child **and** text node from first link of each table row

As `tree.xpath()` intend to return list of text nodes, you can use below to get required text as single string:

```
output = ", ".join(tree.xpath('//tr/td[not(@class) and not(a)]/text() | //tr/td/a[not(../preceding-sibling::td[@class])]/text()'))
```

Comment: Hi, it returns invalid expression in python

Comment: Which tool do you use? Scrapy, lxml, ...?

Comment: I use lxml `tree.xpath('//tr/td[not(@class) and not(a)]/text() | //tr/(td/a)[1]/text()')`

Comment: `", ".join(tree.xpath('//tr/td[not(@class) and not(a)]/text() | //tr/(td/a)[1]/text()'))` also return `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`

Comment: It seem that `lxml` doesn't support `(td/a)[1]` syntax... OK,  I'll try to find another solution